# ¿Cómo generar una lista desplegable con input en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy intentando crear:

- lista desplegable --> `lista=[col1, col2, col3];`
- *input* de tipo texto.

... y con ello añadirlo al *HTML* desde *JavaScript*.

Es decir, lo que estoy intentando hacer es que dada una lista desplegable de ***colegios*** poder añadir al lado el ***profesor*** a través de un botón.

Ejemplo:

```
cole1 juan añadir 
cole2 lola añadir
```

... para después añadirlo en una *tabla*.

```js
var lista_colegios=["cole1","cole1","cole1"];
function crear(){
 var lista=document.getElementById("lista");
 for (var i=0;i<lista_colegios.length;i++){
  document.createElement(li);
  li.innerHTML=lista_colegios[i];
  lista.appendChild(li);
 }
}
```

```html
<ul id="lista"></ul>
<button> onclick="crear()"</button>
```

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende. ¿Con qué datos estás trabajando? ¿qué estructura tienen? ¿de dónde viene? ¿de dónde piensas sacar el nombre del profesor? ¿Por qué no lo muestras con los otros datos cuando creas el HTML?

Comment: Más allá de que el código tiene errores, veo que no hay un intento de crear una lista **despegable**, o quizás habrás querido decir **desplegable**.  Además habías agregado la etiqueta _CCS_, lo cual no hay que confundir con _CSS_, quité la etiqueta, porque curiosamente en la pregunta no hay nada sobre _CSS_ .